# Synchronized Model instances in Django

Tags: django, model, django-orm

I'm building a model for a Django project (my first Django project) and noticed
that instances of a Django model are not synchronized.

```
a_note = Notes.objects.create(message="Hello")  # pk=1
same_note = Notes.objects.get(pk=1)

same_note.message = "Good day"
same_note.save()

a_note.message  # Still is "Hello"

a_note is same_note  # False
```

Is there a built-in way to make model instances with the same primary key to be
the same object? If yes, (how) does this maintain a globally consistent state of all 
model objects, even in the case of bulk updates or changing foreign keys
and thus making items enter/exit related sets?

I can imagine some sort of registry in the model class, which could at least handle simple cases (i.e. it would fail in cases of bulk updates or a change in foreign keys). However, the static registry makes testing more difficult.

I intend to build the (domain) model with high-level functions to do complex
operations which go beyond the simple CRUD
actions of Django's `Model` class. (Some classes of my model *have* an instance
of a Django `Model` subclass, as opposed to *being* an instance of subclass. This
is by design to prevent direct access to the database which might break consistencies and to separate the business logic from the purely data access related Django `Model`.) A complex operation might touch and modify several components. As a developer
using the model API, it's impossible to know which components are out of date after
calling a complex operation. Automatically synchronized instances would mitigate this issue. Are there other ways to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR "Is there a built-in way to make model instances with the same primary key to be the same object?" **No**.

A python object in memory isn't the same thing as a row in your database. So when you create `a_note` and then fetch `same_note` from the db, those are **two different objects in memory**, even though they are the same representation of the underlying row in your database. When you fetch `same_note`, in fact, you **instantiate** a new `Notes` object and initialise it with the values fetched from the database.

Then you change and save `same_note`, but the `a_note` object in memory isn't changed. If you did `a_note.refresh_from_db()` you would see that `a_note.message` was changed.

Now `a_note is same_note` will always be `False` because the location in memory of these two objects will always be different. Two variables are the same (`is` is True) if they **point** to the same object in memory.

But `a_note == same_note` will return `True` at any time, since Django defines two model instances to be equal **if their `pk` is the same**.

Note that if the complexity you're talking about is that in the case of multiple requests one request might change underlying values that are being used by another request, then use `F` to [avoid race conditions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#avoiding-race-conditions-using-f).

Within one request, since everything is sequential and single threaded, there's not risk of variables going out of sync: You know the order in which things are done and therefore can always call `refresh_from_db()` when you know a previous method call might have changed the database value.

Note also: Having two variables holding the same row means you'll have performed two queries to your db, which is the one thing you want to avoid at all cost. So you should think why you have this situation in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, this does not quite answer my question. (1) My point with the `is` comparison is that if `Model.objects.get()` returned the *same* object (i.e. via an internal registry), they would be synchronized automatically. (2) With "complex task" I meant operations which might touch multiple tables and/or multiple records. Assume I have objects `a` and `b`, and run `a.complex_stuff()`. It's not obvious for other developers, who should be required to know the internal workings, that they have to run `b.refresh_form_db()` afterwards.

Comment: I think I answered why you see this behaviour. To answer 1) that's not how this works, so there's no real answer. Just can't be done. 2) I've built plenty of complex projects and never ever hit this issue. Why would you have different objects a and b in the first place in your method if it's supposed to be the same? It just points to bad architecture of your code.

Comment: The question was if there is way to see a different behavior. Your update answers it, Thanks. The objects `a` and `b` might even be instances of different classes, but the complex action on `a` affects database records which change `b` (if refreshed).

Comment: If it's not clear from the name of the method that things are changed, then document your code :-)